# PHP: retrieving a float value from an (input) textfield, non well formed numeric value error

Tags: php

I am writing a simple PHP program to calculate the users BMI and return a string indicating whether he is in the normal range or obese. I have just begun so I need to retrieve the user input from html input elements.  The problem is, I am getting a non well formed numeric value error.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <?php require("header.php") ?>

        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Lab #05 -- BMI Calculator</h1>

        <br /><br /><br />

        <form action="Lab05b.php" method="post">
            <input id="imperial" name="imperial" type="text" value="0.00" /> &nbsp;&nbsp; <label for="imperial">Height in inches / centimeters</label>
            <br />
            <input id="metric" name="metric" type="text" value="0.00" /> &nbsp;&nbsp; <label for="metric">Weight in pounds / kilograms</label>
            <br /><br />
           <input type="radio" name="imperial" id="imperial" value="imperial" /> Imperial 
           <br />
           <input type="radio" name="metric" id="metric" value="metric" />  Metric
           <br /><br />
           <input type="submit" />
           &nbsp;
           <input type="reset" />
        </form>

        <?php require("footer.php"); ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the the Lab05b.php include:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <?php require("header.php") ?>
        <?php require("Lab05b_Functions.php") ?>;

        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Lab #05 -- BMI Calculator</h1>

        <br /><br /><br />

        <?php echo "<p style='color: <?php echo $color; ?>' ?>Your body mass index is in the {$result} range</p>" ?>

        <?php require("footer.php"); ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the functions file:

```
<?php

$imperial = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'imperial');
$metric = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'metric');

    echo $imperial. " " + "imperial units";
    $color = "red";
    $result = "Obese";

?>
```

For this assignment it is ok for the value to be entered into the textfield as an integer.  So right now I am ONLY concerned with tracking down the non wel formed numeric value error.

Thank you for your help,
DB

Comment: Which line is the error complaining about? Also, please post the whole error as well.

Comment: Can you post here result of `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: You've got multiple inputs with the same name, that's not valid. Your radio buttons can't have the same name as the textboxes. Without testing, I'm not sure what PHP will make of that when it tries to create the $_POST values, but it's not a good idea.

Comment: It is complaining about the filter_input line

Comment: what is the _exact_ error message you're getting? Is it actually an error, or a warning? And which of the two lines which call filter_input is the problem, exactly?

Comment: What are you hoping your filter_input call will do, btw? According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php if, as you've done, you omit the third parameter to the function, which denotes the filter to use, then "FILTER_DEFAULT" will be used, so that there is (and I quote) "no filtering taking place by default.". In other words, the function will likely do nothing at all. You might as well write `$imperial = $_POST["imperial"];` directly. Which of the two input fields you've named "imperial" it will end up reading, I'm not sure without testing.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
echo $imperial . " " . "imperial units";
```

Instead of:

```
echo $imperial. " " + "imperial units";
```

`+` is for addition, `.` is for concatenation.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.useful-funcs):

> Strings may be concatenated using the '.' (dot) operator. Note that the '+' (addition) operator will not work for this.